# I can't open the Android SDK and AVD Manager

Tags: android

Alright. I will elaborate the best I can with this problem i have.

I'm a new learner into developing android applications. I installed Eclipse Helios.

I downloaded the Android SDK tools version r10, installed it and stored it in C:\Program Files\Android.

I started up Eclipse and downloaded the ADT Plugin as instructed in the website http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing

After finishing downloading, I'm instructed to download additional components through Android SDK and AVD manager.

I clicked on the Android SDK and AVD button and this message appears:
***"Location of the Android SDK has not been setup in the preference"***

I'm instructed to go to Windows>Preference and update Android Preference SDK address:

I ran into the first problem when this message appeared at the top:

***Could not find C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe!***

Fine I thought. I guess I'll find the file by browsing:

However, after finding the SDK file, nothing happens. I can't click apply or anything! So frustrating!

I read in forums that I should click Help>Check For Updates.. I did that:

After that, I tried to set the Android preference again but nothing changed. I am completely lost. I've no idea what to do or how to solve this problem. I noticed that the file adb.exe does not exist in tools but in platform-tools. But how am I supposed to get the file when the plug in won't even let me download it??

Also I'm curious about this as well:
I went to the SDK file in my C:/ drive to have a look at it.

However, I can't find files that appears when I was browsing the SDK file while setting the Android preference:

I can't access the following files (docs, extras, samples, temp)

I'm also aware that I need to update the PATH environment to platform-tools. Once again, I can't do anything since I don't have the file. I hope this is elaborate enough.

Comment: Any particular reason you installed r10 instead of the latest r12 SDK?  Did you use [the recommended exe installer](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)?

Comment: If you "can't access" files, then you need to fix their permissions. Normal installs do not have this issue. Perhaps you installed the SDK as another user or something.

Answer (score 2):

If you think the problem is whitespace in the path:

Try changing the path to C:\Progra~\Android\android-sdk if you have the SDK stored in Program Files, or

Try changing the path to C:\Progra~2\Android\android-sdk if you have the SDK stored in Program Files (x86), or

Try moving the SDK folder directly to C:.

Answer (score 2):

My ADB(adb.exe) file was not in the platform tools folder.  I went to the Android SDK manager and noticed that the Android Platform Tools had not been downloaded.  I had to change the permissions on the Android Folders to get the install to work. Once the permissions were updated and the Platform Tools was successfully installed, it worked.

You can run the SDK manager outside of Eclipse (if Eclipse won't let you run it).

I updated the Folder permissions in order to get the downloads to work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this is the true issue.
But are you referring to the SDK folder in the "SDK Location" field ?
You referred as SDK File so i imagine that the apply is disabled because it's not the correct folder (like "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\").

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the whitespace in the path.

Answer (score 0):

all.
(I'm sorry for my english).

I faced with the same problem. I use Windows 7 32bit at home and Windows 7 x64 at work. At home and at work I intalled android studio using the same intallation file. But, at work everithing works correctly and doesn't work at home. It should be mentioned, that JAVA_HOME had been added to system variables list earlier as I use maven. However I couldn't launch neither SDK manager nor AVD Manager in Android studio. I tried to find information in the Intenet, but almost everywhere I saw the same: "Setup JAVA_HOME". But I found advice here
[Android SDK and AVD Manager will not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023179/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-will-not-run). It seems, that find_java.bat in ...\android-studio\sdk\tools\lib\ can not define java.exe correctly. I modified android.bat file a little bit and it helped me.

So, I did next thing:

1. Go to the folder, where your android studio was installed. For me, its C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio
2. The go to the sdk\tools folder and open android.bat file for editing (for example, with notepad)
3. Find next text: set java_exe=call lib\find_java.bat and replace it with 
   set java_exe="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java.exe"

Thank you.