# Can't open the SDK Manager

Tags: android, eclipse

I am new to Android Development, ive just downloaded the SDK (The ADT Bundle Containing eclipse and the sdk), installed JDK 1.6 buth when i try to launch the SDK Manager nothing happens. If i run the file ./tools/android.bat no error occurs. I cant get it to run.

CMD Output

```
C:\Users\<user_name>>java -version
java version "1.6.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Users\<user_name>>javac -version
javac 1.6.0_45
```

AVD Runs but not the SDK Manager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open it As Run AS Administrator it will work..

Answer (score 1):

Just confirm the JDK version installed is a x64 version.

Refer this [Android SDK and AVD Manager will not run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023179/android-sdk-and-avd-manager-will-not-run).