# launch standalone SDK manager gives error in android studio 1.5

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-7

i have installed android studio 1.5. After installation i checked SDK manager. it looks fine but once i clicked on `Launch Standalone SDk manager` it does nothing until i close it manually, after that it says cannot launch SDK manager.

i have search on net for similar problem which says there is some problem is environment variable so i did few modification

1. Added `C:\Windows\System32` as it was missing. and added  `JDK bin path` in `path` variable.
2. Also i  have `JAVA_HOME` variable now.

   but even after modification still error is there.

please find the link for screen shot and necessary environment variable of my system.

[SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOeCw.png)

[ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iO9iU.png)

```
path= C:\Windows\System32;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin;

JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73
```

i am confused because i tried to run a sample application it is working fine, than why this error while clicking *`standalone SDK manager`*

Comment: I am facing same issue with android studio 2.2. How did you solve the issue kindly reply?

Answer (score 0):

Change in environment variables sometimes need a system restart or at least an application restart.

Try after restarting the application. If still does not work do a system restart and try.

Also, make sure the paths are absolutely correct and exist by opening them and cross-verifying.

**Update:** From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13658348/1957401) turns out you may need to install (or reinstall) the x64 version of the JDK. The error message in your screenshot also says x64 version not found. The error message also provides the link to download the jdk.

Comment: trying it for 2 days and every time i make any changes in environment variable i am restarting my system. Earlier it was working fine,suddenly i started getting this error.Is it because of anti virus which i have installed recently ? if that is the reason than what step i have to follow.please help...

Comment: i have installed the fresh JDK now but still same error is there.Can any one tell me what are the problem i will  face if **launch  standalone SDK manager**  does't work , as  already mentioned that i have  tested an application and it is working fine and also different SDK platform can be installed from from SDK home page.

Comment: I am facing same issue with android studio 2.2. How did you solve the issue kindly reply?

Comment: i have checked lots of solutions but nothing worked for me, may be i was not following them properly. At last i had to format my system because of some other reasons and i reinstalled android studio.i would suggest you to go through [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82388) .it may help you.